# Adding custom attributes to Task?

Tags: asana

How can i add custom attributes/data to Task via API . for example we wanted to add field like customer contact number or deal amount e.t.c

Comment: Asana has started supporting custom attributes as of Aug'16. read user @utapyngo answer.

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently support adding arbitrary metadata to tasks, though it's something we're thinking about. In the meantime, what many customers do is to simply put data in the note field in an easily-parseable form, which works well and also lets humans reading the task see the e.g. ticket number.

It's not a terribly *elegant* solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/custom-external_data

> Custom external data allows a client application to add app-specific metadata to Tasks in the API. The custom data includes a string id that can be used to retrieve objects and a data blob that can store character strings.

See the `external` field at https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks